# HTML5 Boilerplate with cache handling

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

I have a big doubt about cache handling used in html5 Boilerplate.

I set a cache for header expiry dates 2 year, After 1 year i delete the file from server. But still the cache is present there for 1 more year. How boilerplate handle such situation.? . If this is a normal case we can use ?v=2 to ?v=1 . But in this case am deleted the file from server after setting the cache . So Any idea to solve this issue. ! 
 it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: I just want to know how boilerplate handle cache handling using .htaccess file. if some pre cached file deleted from server. how we can use version control to handle this.

Comment: I don't think you mean [doubt](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=444996)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a get variable to the new site which you are  going to upload. if u change it browser does not recognize this url so it doesn't use any cached file. This is the solution used in html5 boilerplate. using .htaccess file. to know more just reffer html5boilerplate.com. youtube video also available. Hope this helped you. !

Comment: Go through this docs.http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/